# java cucumber.api.cli.main command line usage

Tags: java, class, command-line, junit, cucumber-jvm

Trying to do some automated tests. I am facing difficulty in executing cucumber project from command line instead of eclipse. I know we can do it through cucumber.api.cli.main class (cucumber-core.jar) but I don't know how to use it from command line options.

**Commands tried for Junit execution:**

```
java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore C:/Users/path/workspace/CucumberConcept/src/ cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar;C:/Users/path/workspace/CucumberConcept/src/ org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberConcept.src.cucumber.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore cucumber.CucumberRunner.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner.CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner.java CucumberRunner

java -cp C:/Users/path/Downloads/selenium-java-3.0.1/lib/junit-4.12.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CucumberRunner
```

**Jar file location:**

```
 C:/users/path/lib/cucumber-core-1.2.4.jar
```

**Project Structure:**

```
CucumberConcept
 -src
   -cucumber(package)
      -CucumberRunner.java
     -Features(package)
       -Stepdefinitions.java
       -myfeature.feature
```

**CucumberRunner.java code**

```
package cucumber;

    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

    import cucumber.api.junit.*;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

    @RunWith(Cucumber.class)
    @CucumberOptions(
            plugin = {"pretty","json:target/json/output.json","html:target/html/"},
            features = {"src/cucumber/"}
            )
    public class CucumberRunner {
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `CucumberRunner` that you need to reference in your invocation, but the location of the feature file(s) that you want Cucumber to process.

And to access the Cucumber CLI you have to run the `Main` class, not JUnitCore

So, from `src` I would expect

`java -cp path;more/Path;even/More/Path  cucumber.api.cli.Main .`

to work... as long as the Cucumber jar(s) are on the classpath. AT the very least you'll need `cucumber-core` on the classpath.